# Prevent Flask from changing the url from '/home' to '/static/home'

Tags: python, angular, flask

The app runs only when I build the angular project using `ng build --base-href=/static/` but then `http://127.0.0.1:5000/home` automatically changes to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/home` and the rest of my routes fail, even a refresh button fails as `/static/` route does not exist in my angular routing.

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'demo', component: DemoComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
```

*index.html*

```
<base href="/">
```

*angular.json*

```
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "prefix": "app",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "../static/",
        "index":{
          "input": "src/index.html",
          "output": "../templates/index.html"
        }
```

*server.py*

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: change this `"outputPath": "../static/",` to `"outputPath": "../",` this

Comment: Are you sure? Doing that would create all *.js and *.ico onto the parent directory after `ng build`.

Comment: Your server config should rewrite all *unknown* paths and files to index.html. This way you don’t have to repeat all your angular routes in your flask paths.

Comment: @MikeOne not sure I understand, when the routes are defined in `app-routing.module.ts` why is flask appending static before the actual routes? And how do prevent flask from doing that?

Comment: Did you deploy it to a static folder.. I mean, I’m not sure, hardly a flask expert..

Comment: I have just added `static` to the angular build conf. As flask expects all *.css, *.js to be placed inside `static` and `index.html` in `templates`.